# Show that the function $f(x)=(b-a)x+a$ is continuous with $f:[0,1]\to[a,b]$ in the usual topology

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $A=[0,1], B=[a,b]$, and $(\Bbb R, \tau)$ be the usual topology. Let $(A,\tau_A)$ and $(B,\tau_B)$ be subspace topology of $(\Bbb R,\tau)$. Show that $(A,\tau_A)$ is homeomorphic to $(B,\tau_B)$.

**Attempt:**
Let $f:A\to B$ be a function defined by $f(x)=(b-a)x+a$ for all $x \in A$.
It's clear that $f$ is bijective, and that $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{x-a}{b-a}$.
Now, how to show that $f$ is continuous by doing this theorem: for all $U \in \tau_B$, then $f^{-1}(U) \in \tau_A$?

Let $U \in \tau_B$. We want to show that $f^{-1}(U) \in \tau_A$, i.e., $f^{-1}(U)=int_A(f^{-1}(U))$. For left direction subset is clear by definition. Now, how to show the other direction?
Let $x \in f^{-1}(U)$, then $f(x) \in U$.
We want to show that there is a neighborhood $N$ of $x$ such that $N \subseteq f^{-1}(U)$. Since $U \in \tau_B$, then $U=X \cap B$ for some $X \in \tau$. Since $\tau$ is the usual topology on $\Bbb R$, then $X=\bigcup_{i \in I} (a_i,b_i)$ for some index set $I$ and $a_i,b_i \in \Bbb R$ for all $i \in I$. Hence, $U = (a_k,b_k)$ for some $k \in I$ and so, $f(x) \in (a_k,b_k)$, i.e., $x \in f^{-1}((a_k,b_k)) = (\frac{a_k-a}{b-a}, \frac{b_k-a}{b-a})$.
Thus, we have found a neighborhood $N$ of $x$ such that $N \subseteq f^{-1}(U)$.
Thus, $x \in int(f^{-1}(U))$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, then $f^{-1}(U) \subseteq int(f^{-1}(U))$. Hence, $f^{-1}(U) = int(f^{-1}(U))$ and thus, $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $A$. Since $U$ was arbitrary given, then $f$ is continous.

Now, we want to show that $f$ is open. Let $U \in \tau_A$ be arbitrary. To show: $f(U) \in \tau_B$, i.e., $f(U)=int_B(f(U))$.
Let $x \in f(U)$, then $f^{-1}(x) \in U$. Since $U \in \tau_A$, then $U=A \cap Y$ for some $Y \in \tau$. Since $\tau$ is the usual topology, then $Y=\bigcup_{i \in I} (a_i,b_i)$ for some index set $I$ and real numbers $a_i$ and $b_i$ for any $i \in I$. Hence, $U \subseteq Y$, i.e., $U=(a_m,b_m)$ for some $m \in I$.
Thus, $f^{-1}(x)\in U=(a_m,b_m)$ yields $x \in f((a_m,b_m))=((b-a)a_m+a,(b-a)b_m+a)$. Thus, there is a neighborhood $N$ of $x$ for which $N\subseteq f(U)$. Therefore, since $x$ was arbitrary, then $f(U) \subseteq int(f(U))$. Since $U$ was arbitrary, then $f$ is open.

Therefore, $f$ is a homeomorphism. Thus, $(A,\tau_A)$ is homeomorphic to $(B,\tau_B)$.

I'm in doubt whether the above is correct. Any correction please? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Looks ok. But would probably be a lot easier using the more elementary $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity.

Comment: @bubba Is it correct?

Comment: I would first prove $kx$ is continuous, then that $x+a$ is continuous, then use that the composition of continuous functions is continuous. The advantage of proving those lemmas is that they also makes quick work of the inverse maps which is also the composition scaling and a translation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You proof has the right idea, but formally it is not correct. Let us analyze your attempt.

1. "$X=\bigcup_{i \in I} (a_i,b_i)$ for some index set $I$ and $a_i,b_i \in \Bbb R$ for all $i \in I$. Hence, $U = (a_k,b_k)$ for some $k \in I$."
   No, consider $U = [a,b]$.
2. If $U = (a_k,b_k) \subset [a,b]$, then your argument is correct. However, note that you have directly shown that $f^{-1}((a_k,b_k))$ is an open interval contained in $A$, hence an open subset of $A$. Thus you do not need to show $f^{-1}(U)=int_A(f^{-1}(U))$ for $U = (a_k,b_k)$.

In 1. we have seen that 2. is not enough to prove the continuity of $f$. So what can be done?

We know that $U = X \cap B = (\bigcup_{i \in I} (a_i,b_i)) \cap B = \bigcup_{i \in I} (a_i,b_i) \cap [a,b]$. Thus $f^{-1}(U) = \bigcup_{i \in I} f^{-1}((a_i,b_i) \cap [a,b])$ and therefore it suffices to show that all $f^{-1}((a_i,b_i) \cap [a,b])$ are open in $A$.

If $a_i,b_i \in [a,b]$, then this was proved in 2.

If $a_i \in [a,b], b_i \notin [a,b]$, then $(a_i,b_i) \cap [a,b] = (a_i,b]$. You can show that $f^{-1}((a_i,b]) = (\frac{a_i-a}{b-a},1]$ which is open in $A$.

If $a_i \notin [a,b], b_i \in [a,b]$, then $(a_i,b_i) \cap [a,b] = [a,b_i)]$. You can show that $f^{-1}([a,b_i)) = [0,\frac{b -b_i}{b-a})$ which is open in $A$.

If $a_i,b_i \notin [a,b]$  then either $(a_i,b_i) \cap [a,b] = \emptyset$ or $(a_i,b_i) \cap [a,b] = [a,b]$. This is a trivial case.

Comment: For the first case, how we conclude that $((a_i-a)/(b-a), (b_i-a)/(b-a))$ is open in $A$?

Comment: @PitikKepit Because it is an open interval contained in $A$. Recall the subspace topology.

Comment: Oh, may bad. Thanks sir.

Answer (score 0):

Basic sets in $B$ are of the form $B\cap (a_i,b_i)$. I don't see how you conclude $U=(a_k,b_k)$ from $U=B\cap\bigcup _I (a_i,b_i) $. Take $U=[a,b]\in\tau _B$, for instance ..

---

A simpler solution would be to note that the following are equivalent.

1. $\forall V\in\tau _B,\quad f^{-1}(V) \in \tau _A$.
2. $\forall a\in A, \forall V_{f(a)} \in \mathcal N_{f(a)},\exists U_a \in \mathcal N_a,\quad f(U_a) \subseteq V_{f(a)}$.
3. $\forall a\in A,\forall\varepsilon >0,\exists\delta >0,\forall x\in A,\quad |x-a|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$.

And prove continuity with item 3.

---

If you want to show $f$ is a homeomorphism then you must also verify that $f$ is open i.e $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

Comment: From $U=X \cap B$, I think it's clear that $U \subseteq X$, since it is an equality.

Comment: @PitikKepit and how does that help? Does it imply $U$ has to be of the form $(a_k,b_k)$?

Comment: Since $U\subseteq \bigcup_I (a_i,b_i)$, I think it's imply that $U=(a_t,b_t)$ for some $t$.

Comment: @PitikKepit No, that does not work. Every element in $U$ is in some $(a_k,b_k)$, but all elements don't have to come from the same one. Consider $U=B$. It's a closed interval, you are claiming it to be of the form $(a_k,b_k)$. It is not.

Comment: @PitikKepit And what if $U = (a, c) \cup (c,b)$ with $a < c <b$?